# Search string with jq on any level

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-iam

I want to use `jq` to extract any appeareance of the key `Action` in a JSON file. `Action` appears multiple times in the JSON within different paths (or same path-key-structure with different values).

The use case is to extract all IAM policies that give `*` permissions.

I want to select cases in which .Action is the value "*" or is an array with `"*"` as an element, like

```
"Action":["not this", "*", "not that"]
```

As a plus, it would be good to include the piece of JSON that contains the `"Action"` up to some levels above.

For example this JSON :

```
    {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
```

It would be extracted

```
    {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Action": "*",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        ...
    }
```

Is this achievable with `jq`, and how?

Comment: Yes, it's all achievable, but it's not clear whether you mean the literal string value "*.*" or whether you mean "*.*" in the sense of a string match ("globbing"). Also, please specify the output format. In short, it would help if you followed the [mcve] guidelines. Thanks.

Comment: Its the literal value `*`. I've updated my question, hopefully is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

### Obtaining the paths and objects satisfying the condition

[This section addresses the question as originally worded, that is, when the question specifically asked for the paths to the objects of interest.]

```
paths(objects and has("Action") 
      and (.Action == "*" or (.Action|index("*")))) as $path
| [ $path, getpath($path)]
```

### Collapsing the input based on the selection criterion

```
. as $in
| reduce paths(objects and has("Action")
               and (.Action == "*" or (.Action|index("*")))) as $path
    ({}; setpath($path; $in | getpath($path)))
```

Given input similar to that shown in the Q, the filter immediately above would produce:

```
{
  "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Action": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: this is a great answer, thanks. I upvoted. Prefer not to select as answer because unfortunately still needs work on my part, yet it points in the right direction. Sincere thanks!

Comment: I've initiated a chat in case you want to detail your answer: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186935/room-for-arod-and-peak